# How to access a property of an object which is inside a array assigned to a property of another object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, reactjs, mongoose

How to access the name property of the inside the subjects array?

The database is mongodb.
Change for the course model is not possible.

The course model :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const SubjectSchema = new Schema({

name : {
    type : String
},
description : {
    type : String
},
amount : {
    type : Number
},
});

  //course schema
   const CourseSchema = new Schema({

name: {
    type : String
},
code : {
    type: String
},
passMark : {
    type : Number
},
lectureInCharge : {
    type : String
},
subjects : {
    type : [SubjectSchema]
}

});

//creating model
const Course = mongoose.model('course', CourseSchema);

   module.exports = Course;
```

code which i want access to the subject details of a course?
I want to display the course details with subject details which is inside the
course details. But subjects are inside an array which is assigned to the subject property of the course object.

It is a react interface.

```
 const courses = this.state.courses;
    const updatedCourse = courses.map(function (data,  index) {
        return (
            <div key={index}>
                <p> Name : {data.name}</p>
                <p> Code : {data.code}</p>
                <p> Pass Mark : {data.passMark}</p>
                <p> lecture in charge : {data.lectureInCharge}</p>
                <p> Subjects : </p>
                 //Here i want aceess the ame property of the inside the 
                  subjects array?
                <p> Subject name : {data.subjects.name}</p>
            </div>
        )
    });
```

The json of the which retrieve from the database looks like this.
Included to get an idea how the database looks like.

```
[
{
    "_id": "5cf348111b0ffd3bc02304b8",
    "name": "Software Engineering",
    "code": "SE2019",
    "passMark": 75,
    "lectureInCharge": "Jhon Smith",
    "subjects": [
        {
            "_id": "5cf348111b0ffd3bc02304b9",
            "name": "Computer Architecture",
            "description": "PC Architecture x86 and x64",
            "amount": 2500
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "5cf358991b0ffd3bc02304ba",
    "name": "Computer Networking",
    "code": "CN2019",
    "passMark": 75,
    "lectureInCharge": "Jimmy Perera",
    "subjects": [
        {
            "_id": "5cf358991b0ffd3bc02304bc",
            "name": "Wireless Communications",
            "description": "Introduction to Wireless Communications",
            "amount": 5000
        },
        {
            "_id": "5cf358991b0ffd3bc02304bb",
            "name": "Network Technology Project",
            "description": "Introduction to Network Technology Project",
            "amount": 7000
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
},
{
    "_id": "5cf3593d1b0ffd3bc02304c0",
    "name": "IM",
    "code": "IM2019",
    "passMark": 75,
    "lectureInCharge": "IMIM Jimmy Perera",
    "subjects": [
        {
            "_id": "5cf3593d1b0ffd3bc02304c2",
            "name": "IM Wireless Communications",
            "description": " IM Introduction to Wireless Communications",
            "amount": 3000
        },
        {
            "_id": "5cf3593d1b0ffd3bc02304c1",
            "name": "IM Network Technology Project",
            "description": "IM Introduction to Network Technology Project",
            "amount": 7700
        }
    ],
    "__v": 0
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's an array, you'll need an inner loop (probably another `map`):

```
const courses = this.state.courses;
const updatedCourse = courses.map(function (data,  index) {
    return (
        <div key={index}>
            <p> Name : {data.name}</p>
            <p> Code : {data.code}</p>
            <p> Pass Mark : {data.passMark}</p>
            <p> lecture in charge : {data.lectureInCharge}</p>
            <p> Subjects : </p>
            {data.subjects.map(({name}, i) => (         // <===
                <p key={i}> Subject name : {name}</p>   // <===
            )}
        </div>
    );
});
```